# "Inconvenient" vs. "uncomfortable"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. It's uncomfortable to live there due to poor housing conditions.
> 2. It's inconvenient to live there due to poor housing conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers) However i still feel a bit confused( you say that i should pick up the word that fits in the context. the point is that I know the basic difference between comfortable and convenient, but i can't decide on the appropriate word because i'm almost deprived of any context. "Currently she is living at her mother's with her younger sisters and brothers. It's inconvenient/ uncomfortable to live there due to poor housing conditions" - that's all i have

Comment: You can feel uncomfortable, but you can't feel inconvenient.

Comment: Even that bit about "she's living at her mother's" is more context, and thus helpful. Perhaps you could add that to your question?

Comment: I'm putting this on hold because ***both*** are grammatically correct. We can't tell whether the speaker finds it uncomfortable or inconvenient, or even both at once. It all depends on context, which your comment shows you don't have. (Although the closure reason shows "Proofreading" due to the "Which is correct?" question, it could just as easily be "Unclear what you're asking" because of the lack of context. You really need to fix both to create an objectively answerable question.)

Comment: Dupe @ http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37609/inconvenient-vs-uncomfortable

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything grammatically incorrect in your construction.

I would use "inconvenient" when it means a burden, or where you have to go out of your way to do whatever it is that is the inconvenience.

*Uncomfortable* means that either you are physically not comfortable (as in you are sitting on a very hard chair) or that a situation is awkward.

Just pick the word that conveniently fits into the context.

Usage examples:

- If there's no bus in your neighbourhood and you have to walk a lot,  it may be inconvenient for you.
- I live in the countryside. I have to travel 100 miles to get to my doctor's office. That is inconvenient for me.
- The gas station is open from 6 am to 8 am. That is inconvenient for me, because I like to sleep until 8:30 am.
- I bought some shoes that were a little bit too small. They are very uncomfortable to wear.
- My mattress is very old. It has lumps. It is uncomfortable to sleep on.
- The climate in India is very hot and humid. It is uncomfortable to live there.

The above examples should help differentiate the usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the poor housing conditions are causing real distress then I will say uncomfortable (Mysti gave the example of sitting on a hard chair).

Inconvenient tends to give the idea of something that you just don't like but doesn't really do you harm.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct usage, but they have slightly different meanings.

[Uncomfortable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uncomfortable) is not the same as [inconvenient](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inconvenient).

To know which is more suitable in this case, I'd need to know what it is about the 'housing conditions' that is substandard.

---

> "Currently she is living at her mother's with her younger sisters and brothers. It's inconvenient/ uncomfortable to live there due to poor housing conditions"

In that context I would go with 'inconvenient', although more info would still be useful.